# Big Query Table decorators Absolute time Usage

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to query a daily partition data set visits.

The sets get to a very large size and I need to reduce the BQ costs
I am trying to use snapshots decorators with absolute values in order to get the data , as I so have have the log exact time
in this example I need to pull the logs for an event that happened at 
2018-01-15 08:34:55
I transformed this time to +30/-30 Minutes using this query:

```sql
SELECT INTEGER(DATE_ADD(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), time-30, 'MINUTE')/1000)
SELECT INTEGER(DATE_ADD(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), time+30, 'MINUTE')/1000)
```

and then I created this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [visits_log_20180115@1516007131839-1516003548120]
```

I am getting back an error:

> Illegal table ID: visits_log_20180115@-1516007131839-1516003548120

but if I change it to:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [visits_log_20180115@-1516007131839-1516003548120]
```

I get back a result after a full table scan , Google tutorial from: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators

Doesn't provide example + values for this case and I wonder if it's a syntax error or I am missing out the absolute time frame?

Comment: Are you using a partitioned table or not?

Comment: No , i am using fluentD - td-agent to create a new table every day this query is on a day table that is not partitioned

Comment: I love FluentD. Their config supports time_partitioning_type. Maybe you should reconsider migrating to partitioned tables.

Answer (score 2):

You should switch start and end, as currently your query is `SELECT * FROM [table@end-start]` but it should be `SELECT * FROM [table@start-end]`

So, try

```
SELECT * FROM [visits_log_20180115@1516003548120-1516007131839]
```